# Training accuracy graph with model_to_estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator

I have a Keras sequential model and I'm using:

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I can see the training accuracy printed when I use Keras `fit()` function to train the model.

---

I need to use Estimator API to train the model and I'm using `model_to_estimator` to convert the model to estimator. Then I use `train_and_evaluate()` to train the model.

However I don't see the accuracy graph in Tensorboard. There's only one accuracy value (from evaluation), so the graph is just a dot.

What I need is the accuracy graph from training like the one shown here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators#tensorboard

---

I checked the examples and all I could find were ones where they use Estimator API to build the model and use following code to define a summary scalar.

```
# Compute evaluation metrics.
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,
                               predictions=predicted_classes,
                               name='acc_op')
metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])
```

Does anyone know how to use this with models converted from Keras?

I'm using Tensorflow version r1.10.

Comment: I still couldn't solve this. Could someone upvote for visibility?

Comment: I do the same and it just works. How do you train and evaluate using the estimator? I use the `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate()` function.

Comment: @TasosGlrs I use the same function. You can see the accuracy graph in Tensorboard without any additional configuration? Which Tensorflow version?

Comment: I also use the version 1.10.0. The only difference seems to be the metrics `metrics = ['acc', 'mse']`, but I don't think this would make any difference. Are you sure you give the correct `model_dir` etc.? Also, check your EvalSpec and make sure your algorithm goes into evaluation mode.

Comment: @TasosGlrs Yes my model_dir is correct and it goes into evaluation mode. Problem is, there's only one accuracy value (for the final training step), so the graph is just a dot.

Comment: Oh, but that's because you supposed to have consecutive evals over the training period. Play a bit around with the `tf.estimator.EvalSpec()` arguments, especially `start_delay_secs`, `throttle_secs` and `steps`. Read more about it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EvalSpec

Comment: tf2.0 and the same problem persists!

Comment: @Amila did you find a workaround?